# Get application to show up in start search on openSUSE

Tags: kde, opensuse

I just switched my development environment to openSUSE so I can get more experience with Linux systems. I'm attempting to replicate the 'spotlight' feature on Mac OSX. I've edited the application launcher settings easily enough,  with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. I can open the start menu with the focus on the search bar.

At this point, I attempted to download Sublime Text 2 and have it show up in the search box. I went to the site and downloaded the package and used the Ark program to unzip (un-tar?) the file. I went into the newly created folder and clicked the application icon for Sublime and it opens just fine. But the search function does not list Sublime as an application.

I moved the unzipped folder from `Downloads` to `/opt/` and this does not fix the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1: The correct terminology would be panel and application launcher instead of start menu or start search.

2: Moving the uncompressed file to `/opt/` does not really do anything. It is advised, in order to keep your file system clean. All user-installed apps can go into `/opt/`.

3: Uncompressing the file does not register the application with the application launcher. To accomplish this, right click the app launcher and select "Edit Applications..." From here, you want to select "New Item" and fill in the name field with an appropriate name (I used sublime, no caps), and the only other important field is the command field which is simply a path to the executable (so in my case, /opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime). The tree structure on the left is similar to a directory structure, and you can organize your apps with it. I confess I am still very new to linux and I do not know if there is any great advantage to using this or if there are actual directories that correspond to this. I put Sublime inside of Applications and that's where I plan to put any other apps I download.